# Comment « marrer » a-t-il glissé sémantiquement pour signifier « faire rire » ?

Tags: sens, étymologie

[L'étymologie de « marrer »](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/marrer) :

> *(fin du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle)* [2.] Comme *[marri](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/marri#fr)* (« ennuyé »),
>   [1.] de l’ancien français *[se marrir](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/marir#fro)* (« s’[affliger](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/affliger) »)<sup>[[1]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/marrer#cite_note-Larousse-1)</sup>,
>
> ou de l’espagnol *[marear](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/marear#es)* (« ennuyer »), *marearse* (« avoir le mal de mer ») → voir *[noise](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/noise#fr)*. Il apparait avec le sens de « [s’ennuyer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ennuyer#fr) » puis signifie, par [antiphrase](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/antiphrase), « rire de quelque chose qui devrait plutôt ennuyer<sup>[[2]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/marrer#cite_note-TLFi-2)</sup>. »

[L'étymologie de « marrir »](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/marrir) :

> Borrowed from [Frankish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankish_language) *[*marrijan](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Frankish/marrijan)*,
>    from [Proto-Germanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic_language) *[*marzijaną](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/marzijan%C4%85)* (“to neglect, ignore, hinder, disturb, impede”),
>   from [Proto-Indo-European](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language) **mers-* (“to annoy, forget, ignore, neglect”).

Je ne comprends pas les deux glissements de sens et l'antiphrase dans le sens 2 :

1. Comment « s’affliger » génère-t-il le sens de « ennuyer » ? Si on s'afflige, on ne sera pas ennuyé ?
2. Comment « ennuyer » génère-t-il le sens de « rire » ? Rire de quelque chose qui devrait plutôt ennuyer, me paraît anormal et un symptôme psychiatrique.

Comment: *Antiphrase* semble être la réponse que tu cherches. Cela ne me paraitrait pas surprenant que quelque chose du genre *Qu'est-ce qu'on s'ennuie !* ait pu être utilisé pour vouloir dire *Qu'est-ce qu'on rigole !*.

Comment: Je ne trouve pas de sources convergeant en ce sens, mais je cherche une justification dans le sens de "faire une mare", i.e : réaliser une miction sous soi, le rire perturbant le contrôle de la vessie. Si j'y parviens, je ferai une réponse =)

Comment: Effectivement, je rigole et se marrer sont des expressions à la base qui proviennent de la renaissance, une époque où les dames faisaient sans enlever leurs robes (surtout que c'était long à enlever), les corsets n'aidant pas, il était difficile de se contenir de faire lorsqu'on riait, produisant ainsi une rigole sur les jambes et une marre en définitive.

Answer (score 2):

Je me souviens de ce que mon professeur d'histoire avait un jour raconté. À l'époque des courtisans, charmer une femme passait par le rire. Si c'était réussi, elle se mettait à "uriner", d'où *rigoler*, telle une rigole d'eau, et *marrer*. Je ne suis pas certain que ce soit vrai, mais ça me semble plausible.

Comment: Si ce n'est pas vrai, c'est plausible !