# C'est assez marron !

Tags: sens, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, argot, langage-des-jeunes

I know the word ["marron"](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/marron) and the expression ["être marron"](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre_marron), but none of the senses matches with the apparent meaning of the phrase **"C'est assez marron !"**. I encountered this phrase recently in slang (*argot*) related to urban youth culture (cf. [this inverview](https://youtu.be/B12u_wn8Av8?t=25m10s), one of several occurences). It was used similar to the "C'est bizarre !", "C'est assez bizarre !" or "C'est trop bizarre !", which I hear quite frequently among young people.

> What exactly is meant with this expression? Where does it come from? Is it a regional phenomenon, maybe related to Algerian French? Is it a more recent fashion? What do people think of someone who uses it?

The reason why I ask is simple: I cannot discern what exactly is "marron" about the story the singer tells in the interview. (Not only the story I linked, but she uses it rather arbitrary maybe five times in the same video.)

Comment: I misheard it too when I first heard it on the streets of Paris (where you'll hear it often... along with the expression « dégueulasse ! » ).

Comment: As you are asking about Algerian French; people from Maghreb have sometime a hard time differentiating "an" and "on" sounds when speaking French. Resulting, for instance, in saying "maisan" instead of "maison", or "marron" instead of "marrant".

Comment: @Pierre "ui" too, my "cuisine" sounds as "couisine" :D

Comment: I hear ''marrant'', not marron, and I'm not from Maghreb, the girl in the interview has a good accent, no problem.

Comment: @E.Abdel > Seems the same faulty pronunciation is also a difference between belgians and french ... Already had quite often the remark on "Aujourd'hui", "puissant" or even "juin"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that is a mistake, on dit "c'est assez marrant", "marrant" is an adjective which means as you say, "bizarre", "drôle"..., 
it is an equivalent of "it's funny"

Comment: +1. C'est bien **marrANT** qu'il faut entendre dans cette interview.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses and comments. "Marrant" makes sense to me. Like "marrer" which I know (frequently discussed on this site: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27649/comment-marrer-a-t-il-glissé-sémantiquement-pour-signifier-faire-rire).

Comment: Important to note: the mistake here is on the part of the listener, the sound she pronounces is perfectly in line with /ɑ̃/ as said by younger speakers in the North of the European francophone area

Answer (score 0):

You misheard. In the interview she says « c’est assez marrant ».
It means « it’s funny ».

She does not says « c’est assez marron » which indeed has absolutely no sense in French.

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language SE, Alexy. 
 Does this bring new information from the other answer?  Please take a moment to [tour] the site and see the [help].